# How can I load more the 250 item limit with Google Sheet's =IMPORTFEED()?

Tags: google-sheets, atom-feed

i.e.

this works:

`=IMPORTFEED("http://example.com/feed", "items url", FALSE, 250)`

but this is not:
`=IMPORTFEED("http://example.com/feed", "items url", FALSE, 251)`

How can I get around the 250 item limit?

Comment: Do your feed has more than 250 elements?

Comment: ... yes. Why else would I ask?!

Answer (score 2):

For me, to get round the limit my feed has a start index.

eg

http://www.spoilertv.com/feeds/posts/default/-/Reviews?start-index=1

I can then return 250 items, ie items 1 to 251.

If I want more, I do another IMPORTFEED but this time I use this link

http://www.spoilertv.com/feeds/posts/default/-/Reviews?start-index=251

Repeat this for as many as you need

eg

```
http://www.spoilertv.com/feeds/posts/default/-/Reviews?start-index=501
http://www.spoilertv.com/feeds/posts/default/-/Reviews?start-index=751
http://www.spoilertv.com/feeds/posts/default/-/Reviews?start-index=1001
....
....
http://www.spoilertv.com/feeds/posts/default/-/Reviews?start-index=10001
```

Comment: Is this something you specify in your feed? I was able to get this to work with the spoilertv.com feeds but not with http://feelinggood.libsyn.com/rss. With the Feeling Good podcast feed, I got the same episodes returned from IMPORTFEED whether I used http://feelinggood.libsyn.com/rss?start-index=1 or http://feelinggood.libsyn.com/rss?start-index=30

Comment: @Derek It must be set on the server/service we use. The Feeds from spoilertv run on the Google/Blogger system, so I guess that must be a feature of that feed.

Might be worth checking with libsyn support to see if they have a similar feature for their feeds.